# Python: Increasing a dictionaries values in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to increase the values of the 15 different va1 values by the 15 different va3 values divided by the iteration of the loop dt.

```
import random as r

n = 15
new_dict = {k: {'va1': r.randint(0, 50), 'va2': r.randint(0, 15), 'va3': r.randint(0, 10)} for k in range(n)}

for dt in range(100):
    for va1, va3 in new_dict.items():
        va1 = va1 + va3 / dt 
print(new_dict)
```

I get the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'int'`, which i think means you can't operate on a dictionary value by an integer but surely there's a workaround to this? using a list instead?

Eventually, I'd like to plot the corresponding va1, va2 values (after va1 has been altered by va3/dt) as fixed points moving across a graph using the draw function but can't figure this out. e.g the first va1 value would go with the first va2 value.

Comment: Strictly for this error: `va1 = va1 + va3["va3"] / dt`. But for a complete fix (at least how I understood from the question): `va3["va1"] += va3["va3"] / dt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do. But this might help you solve your problem.

```
import random as r

n=15
new_dict = {'va1': [r.randint(0,50) for k in range(n)], 'va2': [r.randint(0,15) for k in range(n)], 'va3': [r.randint(0,10) for k in range(n)]}
print(new_dict['va1'])
for dt in range(1,101):
    for i in range(n):
        new_dict['va1'][i] = new_dict['va1'][i] + new_dict['va3'][i]/dt
        new_dict['va2'][i] = new_dict['va2'][i] + new_dict['va3'][i]/dt
    print(new_dict)
```

I created each list separately to each dictionary key since there is only three. I did this mostly due to the aspect that you are changing what each list against a key is produced by.

Also change the range for dt as you can't divide by 0.

Comment: Boom! i didn't need the va2 value to increase so i deleted that line but perfect man thanks

Comment: Ahh my bad thought you needed that. Glad I could help.